# FabricJS loadSVGFromString include custom object attributes from SVG URI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I have an SVG string like this one, where I have added some of my own attributes in the URI file string. However when I try to read it into a Fabric canvas using `loadSVGFromString` those attributes are removed.

**Example**

My SVG string can look like this (here with 2 custom attributes `x_rel` and `y_rel`:

`<svg ...><image id="0f83a8ca168e" ... x_rel="0.102367" y_rel="0.013186" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAu ... "/>`

However when I load it using `loadSVGFromString` I get a JSON returned where those attributes are excluded, like this:

```
{
  "version":"4.4.0",
  "objects":
    [
      {
        "type":"image",
        "version":"4.4.0",
        "originX":"left",
        "originY":"top",
        ...
        // MY CUSTOM ATTRIBUTES ARE MISSING HERE!
      }
    ]
  }
```

How do I tell `loadSVGFromString` to include them?

Comment: You should take a look at the static fabric.SHARED_ATTRIBUTES http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.html#.SHARED_ATTRIBUTES